# Nginx Rewrite Rule with PHP not working properly

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an url structure like this:

- https://subdomain.domain.com/overview/test@hotmail.com

And want to rewrite it to:

- https://subdomain.domain.com/triggers/overview.php?technician=test@hotmail.com

To do so I tried around 1000 combinations which all come basically down to this code:

```
location /overview/ {
    rewrite ^/overview/(.+)$ /triggers/overview.php?technician=$1 last;
}
```

I'm using Ajenti, php-fpm 7 & nginx.

Any Ideas?

Also here the whole .conf-File for context:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen *:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /certificates/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /certificates/privkey.pem;


    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/technicians.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/technicians.error.log;

    root /srv/technicians;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # ACME challenge for letsencrypt
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /var/www/letsencrypt.sh;
    }

    # rewrite overview
    rewrite_log on;

    location /overview/ {
        rewrite ^/overview/(.+)$ /triggers/overview.php?technician=$1 last;
    }


    # rewrite urls of requirements
    rewrite ^/requirements/(.*)$ /requirements/$1.html last;


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ajenti-v-php7.0-fcgi-technicians-php7.0-fcgi-0.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. Do you have any access or error logs. Also, you can change the logging level to show the rewrite process in great detail. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log)

Comment: Thx for the input, unfortunately there is absolutly nothing in the error log, even after enabling the rewrite log. I added the whole file for context informations.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the rewrite logging level is "notice", so you will need to change the statement in your configuration to `error_log /var/log/nginx/technicians.error.log notice;` in order to see them.

Comment: Really curious. After hard restarting nginx it worked. Seems like some caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself: The configuration was correct, all I had to do is make sure that nginx is really restarting.

In Ajenti this didn't work through the UI so i tried it through `nginx -s reload`, which worked.